# Find a file and delete some lines within it

Tags: command-line, files, delete

How can I find a specific file and then delete some lines from it using terminal in a single line?

e.g. I want to find `file.txt` in my some specific directory and then I want to delete lines from 5 to 10 within it. Is it possible to do it using a single line command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use...

```
find /path/to/specific/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "file.txt" -exec sed -i.bak '5,10 d' '{}' \;
```

#### Explanation:

- `-maxdepth 1` don't look in any subdirectories of the specified directory
- `-type f` only find files, not directories
- `-exec` do the following command to the found files
- `sed '5,10 d'` delete lines from 5 to 10
- `-i.bak` modify the file itself rather than printing to stdout but make a backup copy of the original file with the extension `.bak`

**EDIT**: although actually if you know exactly where the file is and what it's called you can obviously do

```
sed -i.bak '5,10 d' /path/to/file.txt
```

silly me...

Comment: +1 ... although if you know it's called `file.txt` and that it's at `-maxdepth 1` in `/path/to/specific/directory` ... you don't really need to `find` it ;)

Comment: @steeldriver lol *facepalm*