# How to convert all images from subdirectories to webp

Tags: webp

For example I have a folder called Images and there are 26 folders inside is a,b,c,d contains multiple images each in different format jpg,png,jpeg. How to convert all those images to webp and deleted the originals or else copy converted files to another location with same subfolder name.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251950/imagemagick-convert-cant-convert-to-webp?rq=1) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830694/find-a-file-and-delete-some-lines-within-it)

Answer (score 3):

Foremost I recommend to install `imagick` package on your Ubuntu distro.

If you don't have it installed run `sudo apt install imagemagick` command. Open the folder which you have subfolders containing files with the extensions you want to convert on your terminal.

After that run following command on your terminal:

```shell
find . -type f -name "*.png" -exec mogrify -format webp {}  \; -print && find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -format webp {}  \; -print && find . -type f -name "*.jpeg" -exec mogrify -format webp {}  \; -print
```

You can also combine all above commands in single expression using regex:

```shell
find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\)" -exec mogrify -format webp {}  \; -print
```

To remove the leftovers (original files), run following command afterwards:

```shell
find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\|png\)" -exec rm {}  \; -print
```

For more information about Imagick usage you can find on their official [site](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) and about mogrify [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php).